# Using Doctrine with static YAML databases in Symfony2

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I am familiar with PHP, but only just learning Symfony2 and Doctrine. I am wondering what the best practice is for static data, as in data that is only ever updated when deploying a new version of the web application to production.

I would prefer to specify static data (not schemas) in YAML, because then modifying that data is easy for everyone, whether they know any PHP/Doctrine or not. I would like for non-developers to be able to add an achievement by modifying the .yml file. An example of a static YAML database that I would like to maintain is:

```
Achievements:
  Conservative:
    Difficulty: 2
    Description: >
      Description of Conservative Achievement.
  Dedicated:
    Difficulty: 3
    Description: >
      Description of Dedicated Achievement.
  Persistent:
    Difficulty: 2
    Description: > 
      Description of Persistent Achievement.
```

Now imagine I have an entity representing a User

```
// src/Paulpro/ExperimentingBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace Paulpro\ExperimentingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class User {

    protected $name;
    protected $achievements;

    public function __construct(){
        // Collection of achievements as defined by achievements.yml
        // $this->achievements = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

I want to use Doctrine as normal for Users, so that they are stored in the database and I want Users to be able to earn achievements. A user can have multiple of each achievement, so in my User entity I need some way to represent a collection of achievements with quantities. I do not want the achievements difficulties and descriptions to be stored in the database, only in the .yml file, unless there is a good reason to store the achievements themselves in the database and a good way to import the static data into the database as part of automatic deployment.

I have three main questions related to this problem:

- Is there a better way to do this, keeping in mind that I want non-developers to be able to add achievements easily and I will probably want to overwrite the achievements.yml file for different locales?
- Where in my Symfony2 bundle should I put the achievements.yml file(s)?
- How should I modify the User entity so that the resulting database can maintain quantities of achievements per user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not want the achievements difficulties and descriptions to be
>   stored in the database, only in the .yml file, unless there is a good
>   reason to store the achievements themselves in the database and a good
>   way to import the static data into the database as part of automatic
>   deployment.

A good reason: It will be easier to manage the relations between `Users` and `Achievements`.
A way to import the static data into the database: [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)

### 1. Define your static configuration

The best way to do so, is to [expose a semantic configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html).

In your case, you will have the following 2 files:

```
// src/Paulpro/ExperimentingBundle/DependencyExtension/Configuration.php

<?php

namespace Paulpro\ExperimentingBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * Defines the configuration tree for the bundle
     * 
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('paulpro_experimenting');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('Achievements')->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayNode('Conservative')->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                            ->children()
                                ->integerNode('Difficulty')->defaultValue(2)->end()
                                ->scalarNode('Description')->defaultValue('Description of Conservative Achievement.')->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                        ->arrayNode('Dedicated')->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                            ->children()
                                ->integerNode('Difficulty')->defaultValue(3)->end()
                                ->scalarNode('Description')->defaultValue('Description of Dedicated Achievement.')->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                        ->arrayNode('Persistent')->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                            ->children()
                                ->integerNode('Difficulty')->defaultValue(2)->end()
                                ->scalarNode('Description')->defaultValue('Description of Persistent Achievement.')->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

and:

```
<?php

namespace Paulpro\ExperimentingBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class PaulproExperimentingExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * Load the configuration for the bundle
     * 
     * @param array $configs
     * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        foreach($config as $key => $value)
        {
            $container->setParameter('paulpro_experimenting.'.$key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing so, you will be able to have a better way to manage how your users are using the config. To see a sample of the default config result, you can use the command:

```
php app/console config:dump-reference PaulProExperimentingBundle
```

That should result as following:

```
Default configuration for "PaulProExperimentingBundle"
paulpro_experimenting:
    Achievements:
        Conservative:
            Difficulty:           2
            Description:          Description of Conservative Achievement.
        Dedicated:
            Difficulty:           3
            Description:          Description of Dedicated Achievement.
        Persistent:
            Difficulty:           2
            Description:          Description of Persistent Achievement.
```

This means your users can put this sample in the `config.yml` under the `app\config` folder and change it depending on their need. The only condition is that whatever information they put in this file has to be validate by the `Configuration` tree you have defined.

### 2. Define your entities

Define the `Achievement` entity as it best fits your need. You could for example use:

```
// src/Paulpro/ExperimentingBundle/Entity/Achievement.php
namespace Paulpro\ExperimentingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Achievement{

    protected $name;
    protected $difficulty;
    protected $description;    
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="achievements")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_achievements")
     **/
    private $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

You will keep your `User` entity the way it is except you have to add the relation to `Achievement`:

```
// src/Paulpro/ExperimentingBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace Paulpro\ExperimentingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class User {

    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Achivement", mappedBy="users")
     **/
    protected $achievements;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->achievements = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

### 3. Fill up the database when deploying the app

This is the last step and it uses exclusively the [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

You will have to create the fixture for your `Achivement` entity:

```
// src/Paulpro/ExperimentingBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadAchivementData.php

<?php

namespace Paulpro\ExperimentingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Paulpro\ExperimentingBundle\Entity\Achivement;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoadTypesData implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        foreach($this->container->getParameter('paulpro_experimenting.Achievements') as $key => $value)
        {
            $achivement = new Achivement();
            $achivement->setName($key);
            $achivement->setDifficulty($value['Difficulty']);
            $achivement->setDescription($value['Description']);

            $manager->persist($achivement);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

This fixture will go through the config for `paulpro_experimenting.Achievements` and load the defined `Achievements` from here.
Lastly, to load the data in the database, you will have to run the following command:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

Et voila, you should now be able to add/remove `achievements` from your `users`.

Comment: This looks like a good starting point for me to go from. Thanks for showing an example in such depth!

Comment: Defining the configuration tree can be a bit tricky but it really is the key to get this solution working! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

First things first,

If you are concerned about *what* the achievement thing say or the language used, you can use the **[translator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) component**. Basically what it does is to store your strings in translation files (YAML). So, where you want to add some string, say the achievement name you add some key **achievement.name** and the translator looks for the string for that key. You can have multiple translations and Symfony automatically picks the right one based on the locale of the client. The translator is built into the templates so there is nothing to add but you can use it as well anywhere on the framework.

If you want to get data from files (maybe you want not only the translation but also some structured data), there are some things you can do, you don't actually need Doctrine for this.

**1) Using config.ini**

On every Symfony2 project there is a fille called *config.ini* (on newer versions of the framework it changed to *config.yaml*) in the *app/config/* directory. That file is where things like database configuration values are meant to be stored BUT you can add as many options as you want, just adding them to the file:

```
[parameters]
database_driver="pdo_mysql" 
database_host="192.168.1.1"
...
secret="..."

my_param= "my value"
```

Getting those values is easy, from a controller just call:

```
$this->container->getParameter('my_param'); // returns "my value"
```

It might work for you, but depending on what kind of data you want to store (for *ini* files there is just key/value way to go, and for the newer versions using *yaml* files, I'm just not sure if the framework would parse a hierarchical structure for you (it might, give it a try)). 
Other thing to keep in mind is that if someone deletes a configuration value your system will come down (probably after the cache is manually cleared) and there is sensitive data (a.k.a. passwords) that we generally don't want everybody to know!

**2) Using [YAML component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html) of Symfony2**

First create your YAML file in whatever way it makes sense to you, then place it somewhere on your server (maybe in "resources" or "config" dir?)
Then, if you are on a controller, just write something like:

```
//This line goes at the begining of your file where all the *use*s are
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$file = __DIR__.'/../Path/To/file.yml'; //case sensitive on Unix-like systems 
if(!file_exists($file)){
    throw new HttpException(404, "File not found.");
}
//This line does the magic
$index = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));

//Now $index contain an associative array containing all your data.
```

And you're done! I've used this to load things like menus or generating new sections on a website without touching the code or the database, let your imagination fly!

You can **[create a console command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html)** that import data (from any source you can imagine) to your database and then use that command in some script as part of your deployment process, it's up to you decide if it's worth the effort.

Finally let's just talk about the **entity relations** thing.

It's not all clear what you are trying to do, but there is no (clean/nice) way to add relationships between a Doctrine entity and a random configuration file. The problem is that they are meant to perform different roles in the app.

I'd suggest you do something like this:

1. On your database:

   - Add a table "achievements" with an **id** and a column called **nameKey** and maybe **descriptionKey** ... These __Key columns will contain **translator keys** (as mentioned before). I.e:

   "ID":1, "nameKey":"achievement.1.name", "descriptionKey":"achievement.1.description"
   "ID":2, "nameKey":"achievement.2.name", "descriptionKey":"achievement.2.description"
   "ID":3, "nameKey":"achievement.3.name", "descriptionKey":"achievement.3.description"

   - Then modify your User so it links to the *achievements* table.
     Keeping this in your database will help you and enable you to use some other nice Symfony tools (like forms, validators, ...) and help you keep integrity in your data.
2. Using translator

   - Create a translation file for each lang. you are interested, they will look like:

   achievement.1.name: "Best player ever"
   achievement.1.description: "Blah blah blah"
   achievement.2.name: "Better than average"
   achievement.2.description: "Blah blah blah"

just follow the documentation to see how to output your strings translated wherever you want to put them.

To add new records you would need to add a record on the database (if you want to make it easier, just write a small web form for that) and the translation keys.

*Symfony is so powerful yet easy that will make you lazy and productive at the same time*

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use a class to represent your Achievements. 
I would also propose to use a relational database to store relations between Users and Achievements (logic :) )
I mean that I would prefer to store achievement in database.
Using [alice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice) it's quite easy, and your yaml file has not that much to change.

It's a 2 steps process:

- modifiy yaml to fit alice needs
- create an Achievement entity and add relations between user and it

```yaml
Achievement:
  Conservative:
    id: 1
    Difficulty: 2
    Description: >
      Description of Conservative Achievement.
```

```php
<?php

class Achievement
{
    public $id;
    public $difficulty;
    public $description;
}
```

Follow then the alice steps, and you have a working solution.

**Another possibility** is to simply store the Achievement keys as serialized array in your user entity:

```php
<?php

class User
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type="array") **/
    protected $achievements = array();

    public function addAchievementByName($name)
    {
        $this->achievements[] = $name;
    }

    function getAchievements()
    {
        $self = $this;
        $allAchievements = Yaml::load(__DIR__.'/path/yo/yaml/file');
        return array_flip(array_filter(array_flip($allAchievements), function($achievement) use ($self) {
            return in_array($achievement, $self->achievements);
        }));
    }
}
```